# Concatenate variable between line of code

Tags: javascript

**query variable**

```
query = '.where("user_agent", "==", "'+ useragent +'").';
```

Append `query` variable between these line of code:

```
where("end_time", ">", sessionTime)
+ query +
get().then(function(querySnapshot)
```

While running this code, it gives an error:

> ReferenceError: get is not defined

Comment: Why should `get` be defined? Nowhere in the code you have shown us is there anything that might define it.

Comment: Given your code, `get()` is not defined. Why do you expect it to be?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `eval()` for that

```
let query = '.where("user_agent", "==", "'+ useragent +'").';

eval(`where("end_time", ">", sessionTime)
+ ${query} +
get().then(function(querySnapshot)`;
```